# are there potential pitfalls to using static methods in a web application (.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods

From the web app, calls are made to a web service that in turn makes calls to a few static helper classes for filtering and sorting data - trying to think ahead if I will have unexpected behavior with multiple users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your static methods are thread-safe.

Thread safety fundamentally deals with ensuring that two threads don't access a shared resource in a conflicting manner.

There's a great overview on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

The best tutorial I have ever found about threading in the .NET environment is [by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: A little complex to cover in an answer to a question that's not about thread safety directly, but added two great sources of information for further reading.

Comment: ObjectDataSource dictates that we use static methods in a DALC - are these thread safe during multiple requests?

Comment: Thread safety is a complex issue... if they are initialized with proper locks, using static methods as a shared read-only cache should be thread safe.  If they can be updated from one thread while read from another, it's not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

No, as long as those methods don't share access any shared resources.  This could be:

- A file on disk
- Some static data
- Another external resource

You just have to be sure that you aren't inadvertently sharing any resources / static data.

Answer (score 1):

Using static methods is no issue. Just don't use static state unless you can synchronise access and keep performance